# how to get all infusionsoft contacts - PHP api?

Tags: php, sdk, contacts, infusionsoft

Basically I just want to get all contacts of an app/account from Infusionsoft. I'm using PHP SDK from their documentation. Currently I can get contacts by using this:

```
$contacts = $infusionsoft->contacts()->all();
```

But this function is somewhat deceptive as it only returns `1000` records. What I wanted to do is get `ALL` contacts. We currently have over 10k+ contacts or even more. Any idea would greatly help. Thanks

I'm reading their documentation as well as the `PHP-SDK sources` but to no avail. I just want to have a way of iterating the contacts from Infusionsoft like some pagination of some sort. That would really help.

Comment: I took a look at their docs `https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/#!/Contact/listContactsUsingGET`. It appears that you can set an `offset`, so for example if there is a max of 1,000 (dunno) per request, then you can use `offset` to get the next 1,000, and so on.

Comment: @GetSet This api will not work. To use the API via php you need to use legacy infusionsoft xml api

Comment: @nektobit is it okay to use the legacy xml api? I'm getting deprecated warnings here and there. will it be okay just to try to hide it ?

Comment: @silent_coder14 there is nothing good in using legacy api. But, you simply have no other choice if you run a script that works with infusionsoft, for example, according to the cron timer. Because the current rest api requires oauth2 and you cannot get access token except from the browser. Now I am conducting a dialogue with developers to solve this problem, but they are not particularly in a hurry because they now have complex processes in the company associated with "keep".

Comment: Yes, that's the real pain with Infusionsoft. You have to authorize first the client using oauth and then refresh the token every now and then to continue using it with CRON jobs. The legacy one is good since we just need the key to access the api but it's on "legacy" so yeah.

Comment: I'm having a hard time with REST API too because I believe they don't have a comprehensive documentation for their classes and methods. Just like the answer of @Michael Fairchild below, I tried to use it with the orders data. I'm successful but I'm getting protected property and I'm kinda lost where to find the methods to access those properties.

Comment: @silent_coder14 you are right. https://community.infusionsoft.com/t/0auth-without-browser/75182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little deceptive. It was built to mimic Laravel's Eloquent models however all the functionality wasn't implemented. You'll have to paginate manually.

You can use something like the following:

```php
$contacts = [];
$limit = 1000;
$offset = 0;

do {

$results = $infusionsoft->contacts()->where('limit',$limit)->where('offset', $offset)->get();

array_merge($contatcs, $results->toArray());

$offset += $limit;

} while (count($results->toArray()) == 1000);
```

Comment: thank you for this. I used this too for orders but I'm getting protected object attributes when trying to get items. Any idea how to use the results?